# Convert jQuery to Pure JavaScript for Sticky YouTube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to convert jQuery to pure JavaScript to achieve sticky YouTube video in nuxt but I am facing some problems. The JQuery is:

```
var $window = $(window);
var $videoWrap = $('.video-wrap');
var $video = $('.video');
var videoHeight = $video.outerHeight();

$window.on('scroll',  function() {
  var windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var videoBottom = videoHeight + $videoWrap.offset().top;
  
  if (windowScrollTop > videoBottom) {
    $videoWrap.height(videoHeight);
    $video.addClass('stuck');
  } else {
    $videoWrap.height('auto');
    $video.removeClass('stuck');
  }
});
```

And also if I try to create a Js file  and add this code I am getting videoHeight undefined.

Comment: Did you tried to use a basic `video` tag and some CSS? Why is everything done in jQuery here?

Comment: @kissu on scroll if a user has reached the particular section im my html I want to show the sticky video. And so I caluclated the height of the video by jquery.

Comment: Still, this can totally be done with CSS IMO. Can you explain us a bit more what it should look like please?

Comment: https://youtube-sticky.webflow.io/ something like this. Just scroll and see the video position changing to the right and fixed